# Troubles when installing Morse Robot Simulator on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, simulator, robot

I'm trying to install the Morse Robot Simulator on my Ubuntu 12.04, but when I try to use the command "cmake .." it give some errors...

```
-- will install python files in /opt/lib/python3.2/site-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named yarp
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (MESSAGE):
  BUILD_YARP_SUPPORT is required, but '/usr/local/bin/python3.2' can't find
  yarp python binding
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [install YARP](http://wiki.icub.org/yarpdoc/install.html) and its [Python bindings](http://wiki.icub.org/yarpdoc/yarp_swig.html). The error message is complaining about the latter. Note that since you're using a custom `/usr/local/bin/python3.2` instead of Ubuntu's python package you'd need to account for that.